# Broth of a boy etymology

Tags: etymology, idioms

Could anybody explain the etymology of the phrase *broth of a boy*? I know the meaning but cannot understand how it happens that it means what it means.

Comment: Well, you take a large kettle, place a boy in it, and cook until you have a broth.

Comment: Irish in modern usage - see 1959 film of tat name. Oxford Dictionaries says *used approvingly to refer to a very lively boy or young man*. Etymology *Old English, of Germanic origin*; related to *brew*.

Comment: Can you give a sentence or paragraph of context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Broth of a boy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sYScAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA178&dq=%22broth%20of%20a%20boy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Cm8lVdusN4WHsAXysIGIAg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22broth%20of%20a%20boy%22&f=false), from page 178 of the *Concise Oxford English Dictionary: Luxury Edition*:

> Irish a very lively boy or young man.
> ORIGIN OE, of
> Gmc origin; rel. to BREW

*Broth of a boy* is thought to be of Irish origin, not directly from English *[broth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=broth&searchmode=none)*, but probably from a similar linguistic stock:

> Old English broþ, from Proto-Germanic *bruthan (cognates: Old High
> German *brod),
>
> from verb root *bhreue- "to heat, boil, bubble; liquid
> in which something has been boiled" (source also of Old English
> breowan "to brew;" see *[brew](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brew&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.)).
>
> Picked up from Germanic by the Romanic and Celtic languages.
>
> The Irishism *broth of a boy*, which is in Byron, was "thought to
> originate from the Irish *Broth*, ***passion*** -- *Brotha* ***passionate***, spirited ..." [Farmer], and if so is not immediately related.
>
> *[brew](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brew&allowed_in_frame=0)*
>
> Old English breowan "to brew" (class II strong verb, past tense breaw,
> past participle browen),
>
> from Proto-Germanic *breuwan "to brew"  (cognates: Old Norse brugga,
> Old Frisian briuwa, Middle Dutch brouwen, Old High German briuwan,
> German brauen "to brew"),
>
> from PIE root *bhreuə- "to bubble, boil, effervesce" (cognates:
> Sanskrit bhurnih "violent, passionate," Greek phrear "well, spring,
> cistern," Latin fervere "to boil, foam," Thracian Greek brytos
> "fermented liquor made from barley," Russian bruja "current," Old
> Irish *bruth "**heat**;"* Old English beorma "yeast;" Old High German brato
> "roast meat"),
>
> the original sense thus being "make a drink by boiling."
>
> *Etymonline.com* ***Emphasis*** mine